# touchesBegan/touchesMoved

Tags: uiimageview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I am trying to do an app in which you have an image only. Then when the user touches the image a copy is created and then the image can be moved to another location and drop it there.

This is the code I have created:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touch_point = [myTouch locationInView:view1];

    if ([view1 pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event]) {
        UIImageView *view= [UIImageView alloc];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [view release];
        view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 100.0);
        view.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    }       

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint touch_point = [myTouch locationInView:view1];

    if ([view1 pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event]) {
        view.image=view1.image;
    }

}
```

My problem is I cannot access the *view created in the `touchesBegan` and use it in `touchesMoved`. Does anybody know hoy to make this image view public?